# Is it possible to take apart a manfrotto monopod for transportation?

Tags: travel, diy, monopod, manfrotto

I'm about to buy a Manfrotto 562B. It folds down to about 27 inches but I would like to make it even smaller for transportation purposes.

Is it possible to take it apart? Do you know how?
The idea is to "break it" into two pieces and then put it back together on arrival.

How much of a terrible idea is this? Have you done something similar before?

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: what about spending a few hundreds of dollars? ^^ http://reallyrightstuff.com/WebsiteInfo.aspx?fc=68  (some of them, like the TQC-14 or TQC-24 are smaller than yours, and probably sturdier and taller when extended? see http://reallyrightstuff.com/mmrrs/Images/gallery/choose_a_tripod.jpg )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since each leg section is nested in the next when the monopod is compacted, splitting it in two won't result in either section being much smaller than entire monopod. Each section appears to be around 22-23 inches long. What you can do is remove the head, but you're not going to gain much there. Looking at the [parts diagram](http://mediacdn.shopatron.com/media/mfg/2747/media_document/live_2/562B_20070216.pdf?1272346470.) published by Manfrotto, it appears removing the feet from the shaft would be a very involved operation and would risk losing some small bolts and nuts that hold it together. The fluid cartridge that makes this monopod unique does not appear to be detachable from the smallest section of the monopod's shaft.

Comment: Did you mean _losing_ the small bolts (or perhaps _loosening_)?  "Loosing" doesn't make much sense there.

Answer (score 6):

I've put mine back together a few times after one of the dividers keeping it from falling apart failed, so in theory you could do it. 
But it's not worth the trouble, and leaves the monopod weak and prone to falling apart on you again when you don't want it to.
It also increases the total volume you'll be taking with you, for very little reduction in the length of the longest piece.

In all, a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks! It truly seems like it is not worth the trouble.